# MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE anternativa

Tags: java, android, google-play

MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE es rechazado por google. Tengo un app que obtiene PDF invocando a un API. Luego, permite abrirlo en acrobat y visualizarlo. Alguien tiene alguna idea como como hacerlo sin usar el permiso MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?. Por favor su ayuda.

Uso el permiso MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE pero google lo rechazó al publicarlo.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files

Comment: Bienvenido, trata de explicar lo que estás realizando y agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.